# How to get current local format date from system in C or C++ which can be run on all platforms

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos

I am using this [GetDateFormat method from MFC C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformata) to get the current date format from the system.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st, lt;
    TCHAR szTime[256];

    GetSystemTime(&st);
    GetLocalTime(&lt);
    GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_SHORTDATE, &st, NULL, szTime, 250); // prints current date format from system

    cout << szTime << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Scenario: If I change the date manually in my system from `YYYY-DD-MM` to `DD-M-YY`, then it should be print the updated date format if I run the program again.

With the above code I am able to achieve it but I think `GetDateFormat` is only specific to windows API. Is there any API to achieve the same in Mac OS and Linux?

**Update:**

Approach 2: Prints date in expected format but not sure if I can use this in all platforms?

```
/* setlocale example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */
#include <locale.h>     /* struct lconv, setlocale, localeconv */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  struct lconv * lc;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  int twice=0;

    setlocale (LC_ALL,"");
    strftime (buffer,80,"%x",timeinfo);
    printf ("Date is: %s\n",buffer); //prints date in expected format

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current "localized pattern" for the date and time of an std::locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750954/how-do-i-get-the-current-localized-pattern-for-the-date-and-time-of-an-stdlo)

Comment: @ChrisMM I have already tried it but it doesn't output the expected date format from system

Comment: Please confirm you tried this with just "%x" in the format string.

Comment: @Spencer No. Where do I add "%x"? I am new to c++

Comment: @Spencer You meant this line: `tmput.put(s, s, ' ', my_time, '%x');` ?

Comment: Using `tmput.put(s, s, ' ', my_time, '%x');` gives: 
`user settings: 04/24/20
C settings: 04/24/20` But the date format in system is `DD.M.YY`

Comment: How did you set the system date format? through a shell command? A config file?

Comment: Did you set the language/locale and use the default format from that?

Comment: @Spencer I didn't set any local/language. I just went and updated the date in my system from short date to long date and ran the program. It works

Comment: @Spencer But not sure if this code(approach) can be compiled and run in different platforms?

Comment: @kittu By "It works" do you mean the `date` command in a Linux shell returns the date in the right format?

Comment: @Spencer I tested this code on windows for now. Its C++ code right and C++ is cross platform so I guess I should be able to compile this code and run on Linux etc?

Comment: Why anybody isn't answering about my approach 2 whether its work on all platforms?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    // If you want to set a specific local then use the appropriate local object.
    std::locale lJP("ja_JP");
    std::cout.imbue(lJP);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Ec") << "\n";

    // To pull the system local used by your system then use the empty string.
    std::locale lSY("");
    std::cout.imbue(lSY);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%x") << "\n";
}
```

Running this:

```
> ./a.out
金  4/24 09:42:27 2020
Fri Apr 24 09:42:27 2020
```

You can find the standard valid conversions [here](http://ld2013.scusa.lsu.edu/cppreference/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time.html):

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Comment: what about approach 2 I have tried? Will it work on any standard complaint compiler ?

Comment: @kittu Just leave out the four lines where the Japanese locale is set and instead use the "to pull the system local"  part where `locale("")` is set. You tagged this question [tag:c++] so Martin is giving you a C++ approach rather than a C approach.

Comment: @Spencer I have tagged C also but some one removed it

Comment: @Martin I edited your post to reduce it to just the stuff OP wants. Feel free to revert it.

Comment: @Martin Removed 4 lines and ran. It prints empty line

Comment: @kittu If it throws then you don't have the specific local installed on your machine. In this example I specifically use `ja_JP` as an example as I happen to have this locale. If you don't then it will crash. But the locale "" will pull the current system locale which will never crash.

Comment: @Martin That is fine but I'm not able to get it to print the system locale.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. This just prints the locale date instead of current system locale date that is set in the computer as per user desired date format